# PHP 5 and "& new"

Tags: php

this statement:

```
$node_obj =& new someClass($somearg, $moreargs);
```

generate an error in the latest version of PHP right?

I have tried it on my machine (PHP >= 5.0.0 & <=5.2.17) and I get this error:

> Deprecated: Assigning the return value of new by reference is deprecated in test.php on line 1108

Comment: That is a deprecated notice, much less severe than an error. But they're good to fix nevertheless of course

Answer (score 24, accepted):

Remove the `&`.

Objects are passed as reference by default in PHP 5, which is why using the `&` is deprecated in this context.

Comment: If I remove &, then I get an error in the oldest version of PHP right ?

Comment: There will be no error, but the behavior may be subtly different.  Regardless, you should not be coding your scripts with PHP4 compatibility in this day and age.  PHP4 has been unsupported for years.

Comment: @xRobot not an error as such, but the behaviour will be different in PHP 4. But that should not really be a concern any more in 2010, PHP 4 is really dead.

Comment: I *wish* PHP4 were dead. I'm on a project right now where I have to make code that runs on both! Upgrade not until next year :(

Comment: @webbiedave arrrggh! That's awful. And *I* felt unfairly treated by life because I can't make use of *5.3* everywhere yet....

Comment: @webbie on the other hand, looking at the rate at which PHP 6 comes forth, we will all have a *lot* of time to enjoy the delights of 5 :)

Comment: lol. I say "arrrggh" everyday! Yes PHP5 will be with us for a long time to come.

Comment: 4 years later ... `Oo` What happens underneath when using & in front of the new operator under php4 ? (Doesn't `new` purpose be to return a newly created object reference ?)  (What difference it makes ?) I just can't figure why sometimes such instructions are used `$foo =& new Foo();` `:(` I hope someone will explain me .. Many thanks in advance !

Comment: I had never run into this until I upgraded from PHP 5.6 to 7.0 and nearly every PEAR extension I was using began to throw fatal errors. The solution was exactly as described: remove the `&` in all instances of `&new ...`. Unfortunately, the offending PEAR libraries were completely up-to-date, so, I'll need to fork or submit a patch to continue using them reliably.

Answer (score 0):

So, you've got this or similar error:

```
Parse error: syntax error, unexpected 'new' (T_NEW) in 
/usr/share/php/PEAR/Config.php on line 650
```

Proper fix would be to upgrade all PEAR libraries. But since (as time of writing) there's none, here's how to fix all these errors in PEAR when running PHP 7.

#### Before the fix.

```
find /usr/share/php -type f -name \*.php | xargs grep '&new' | wc -l
```

Returns 77 occurrences.

#### Now comes `sed` magic

```
find /usr/share/php -type f -name \*.php | xargs sed -i 's/&new/new/g'
find /usr/share/php -type f -name \*.php | xargs sed -i 's/& new/ new/g'
```

#### After the fix

Previous code returns zero occurrences.

You may also want to add this somewhere in `PEAR.php`:

```
function set_magic_quotes_runtime() {}
```